# Let $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ a measurable and bounded set. Show that exists for each $0<\alpha<1$ an interval $I$ such that $m(A\cap I)/m(I)>\alpha$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ a measurable where $0<m(A)<\infty$. Show that exists for each $0<\alpha<1$ an interval $I$ such that 
$$
\frac{m(A\cap I)}{m(I)}>\alpha.
$$

**MY ATTEMPT**: Following a hint a give that:

Let $\varepsilon>0$, exists $G$, a open set such that $m(A)\leq m(G)<m(A)+\varepsilon$. As $G$ is open, we can write as the disjoint sum of open intervals $\dot{\bigcup}_n I_n = G$.So,
$$
m(A)\leq m(G)=m\left(\sum \dot{\bigcup_n} I_n \right)\leq \sum m\left(I_n \right)<m(A)+\varepsilon
$$
Suppose that $\varepsilon=(\alpha^{-1}-1)m(A)$:

$$
m(A)+\varepsilon=m(A)+m(A)(\alpha^{-1}-1)=m(A)(1+\alpha^{-1}-1)=m(A)\alpha^{-1}
$$
and
$$
\alpha\sum m(I_n)<m(A)=\sum m(A\cap I_n)
$$
$$
\Rightarrow \alpha<\frac{\sum m(A\cap I_n)}{\sum m(I_n)} 
$$

But I have a insecurity with that:

(1) I can write that: $m(A)=\sum m(A\cap I_n)$?

(2) How to get the result with this: $$
\alpha<\frac{\sum m(A\cap I_n)}{\sum m(I_n)} 
$$

Answer (score 3):

Here is another approach (I assume $m$ is Lebesgue measure): if, to the contrary, $m(A \cap I) \le \alpha m(I)$ for every interval $I$ you would have $$m(A) \le m \left( A \cap \cup I_k \right) \le \sum_k m(A \cap I_k) \le \alpha \sum_k m(I_k)$$ whenever $\{I_k\}$ is a covering of $A$ by intervals. What is the *definition* of $m(A)$?

Comment: $m(A)=\inf\{\sum m(I_n): A\subset \cup I_n\}=\sup\{\sum m(I_n): A\supset \cup I_n\}$

Comment: Correct. Can you complete the argument?

Comment: This implies that $m(A)\leq \sum m(I_k)$ for **any** covering of $A$, right? This is a problem? (not necessarily the inf/sup belongs to the set... )

Comment: This implies that $m(A)\leq \alpha \sum m(I_k)$ for any covering of $A$. This is a problem because it implies that $m(A)\leq \alpha m(A)$ with $0<\alpha <1$.